# How to format JSON code quickly on Linux OS?

Tags: json, formatting

I am having a very large JSON file, but it's poorly formatted so that all the chars are in one line only, no `\n` anywhere, which makes it difficult to read and understand. And since it's more than one kilobyte file, editing it manually is out of the question.

I am looking for a command or some other way to format a JSON file quickly, for human readability, and save it into the same file or another one. Ideally I shouldn't have to setup too many things. I know that some IDEs include automatic formatting features, however installing another IDE onto my work computer is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is in a file? You could do this:

`python -m json.tool my_json.json`

Built into python from version 2.5? 2.6? And it will pretty-ify the json for you.

Comment: The other alternative is to open the file in chrome (if you use it, there are equivelents for firefox IIRC) with the json extension JSONView:

chrome://extensions/?id=gmegofmjomhknnokphhckolhcffdaihd)

Comment: Of course I have python. Yes, it actually worked! And I was able to redirect it into another file, just how I wanted. No copy paste nonsense. I will probably accept this answer, but I want to wait to see what different solutions other people can come up with.